# Lagrangian under time transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, energy, lagrangian-formalism, noethers-theorem

> Given a Lagrangian $$L(q,\dot{q},t)=\sum_{ij}a_{ij}(q)\dot{q}_i\dot{q}_j-V(q_1,q_2,\cdots,q_f)$$show that under a time transformation $t=\lambda T$ ($\lambda$ = constant), the invariance of $\int_1^2Ldt$, with respect to the variation of $\lambda$ implies that the energy is zero.

My work:

Basically I need to calculate the variation, so I did this, $$\delta \int_1^2 L(q,\dot{q},t)dt = \delta \int_1^2 L(q,\lambda^{-1}\dot{q},\lambda T) \lambda dT.$$ Now from here, how do I proceed?

Comment: This is a consequence of Euler's homogeneous function theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Positive_homogeneity

Comment: @Phoenix87 Could you be more specific? I can't relate the two.

Comment: Which source is the problem from? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic: Its from this book, http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=rana+joag+classical+mechanics
Problem # 6.5. I guess you won't get a PDF copy of this online.

Comment: you know that the lagrangian you are given is a function with the property $f(x,\lambda \dot x, \lambda t) = \lambda f(x,\dot x, t)$

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. Use [Noether's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) twice.
2. Since there is no explicit time dependence, the energy function $h:=\dot{q}^i\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^i}-L$ is a constant of motion.
3. The Noether charge for time dilation is the product $Q=th$ of time and energy.
4. Since the Noether charge $Q$ is a constant of motion, the energy $h$ must be zero.

Comment: Admittedly, the problem 6.5 in Rana & Joag seems somewhat contrived, apparently solely constructed to make a class room problem about Noether's theorem.